# Push all elements of array into new array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using aggregation framework. One of the early steps produces an array via a group. In the next group step I would like to create an array that is an aggregate of the grouped arrays.

I have tried using `$push : "$myArrayField"` but this produces an array of arrays. Is there a way to create an array of the values in the array field without doing an unwind?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way do this without using an `$unwind` phase between the 2 `$group` phases

Comment: I have noted this with a Jira ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16284